# NetworkManager is not changing MTU setting

Tags: networking, network-manager

I'm trying to change my MTU size on my ethernet interface.

I'm just using Ubuntu 22 Desktop, i've set my MTU value to 10000 through the Gnome network settings:
[image]

I've then restarted NetworkManager `sudo restart NetworkManager`.

My MTU does not seem to change when I check with `ifconfig`:

```
ifconfig | grep mtu
enp39s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
```

This is my whole NetworkManager profile from `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 1.nmconnection`:

```
[connection]
id=Wired connection 1
uuid=02d40a9e-d675-390b-a1d1-f28ff3b23880
type=ethernet
autoconnect-priority=-999
interface-name=enp39s0
metered=2
timestamp=1697903662

[ethernet]
mtu=10000

[ipv4]
address1=192.168.178.2/24,192.168.178.1
method=manual

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
method=auto

[proxy]
```

I have not manually modified this file, only used the GUI.

The NetPlan configuration is unchanged from default:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

nmcli appears to be set correctly `nmcli connection show 'Wired connection 1' | grep mt`:
`802-3-ethernet.mtu:                     10000`

I'm stumped, does the interface inside `ifconfig` not represent what NetworkManger changes? Has it actually been changed? I can't tell.

The output of `ip -d link list dev enp39s0` is:

```
2: enp39s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC was here> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 minmtu 68 maxmtu 9194 addrgenmode none numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 64000 gso_max_segs 64 parentbus pci parentdev 0000:27:00.0
```

Comment: IMHO An increase in MTU requires reallocation of lots of buffers deep within your network stack. I'm not sure the code to do this exists. Try restarting your network service

Comment: Modern Ubuntu releeases use the `ip` commands, rather than `ifconfig`. Do: `ip link`. Set MTU: `sudo ip link set dev enp39s0 mtu 10000`. Read `man ip ip-link ip addr networkmanager`.

Comment: Are you sure your NIC supports 10k MTU? What is the output of `ip -d link list dev enp39s0`? [Edit] your question to include the output... Commonly NIC's max out at ~9k.

Comment: @waltinator you are correct, the maximum is `9194`. Setting an MTU of 9000 works, write an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum MTU supported by the card is 9194 bytes, as shown by `ip -d link list dev enp39s0`.

Setting it to 10k fails, and thus the default of 1500B is used.